# Console in Chrome Devtools doesn't clear on refresh after update 68

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

After the version 68 update a couple weeks ago, my console in Devtools no longer clears after refreshing the page. Here are the console settings:

[image: Chrome console settings]

So unless I'm misunderstanding something, the console should be cleared upon refreshing the page, or navigating somewhere.

This was working fine until the version 68 update. (which broke the feature immediately, I noticed within a couple minutes since I use this console quite a bit)

Any reason that it wouldn't be clearing?

Comment: I have the same issue on my machine on Version 68.0.3440.106

Comment: @johnFu I finally tracked down the issue here. Hopefully my answer solves the problem for you too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the issue was an extention: "adBlocker Plus". I'm surprised I couldn't find many complaints about this issue.

I tested it about a dozen times. Disabling the extention fixes the problem.

I've had too many issues with AdBlock Plus in the past, so I'm switching to uBlock going forward. The same custom filters work, and it actually runs a little faster, too. :D

Comment: hmm... I don't have ABP installed though.

Comment: @JohnFu - bummer. You could try running in "incognito" mode (which by default disables all extensions and such). If it works in "incognito" mode, than that means an extension is probably causing the issue.

Comment: @skeets how did you figure this out?

Comment: @DanOswalt I disabled all extentions by trying incognito mode. When that worked, I Knew it was an extention causing the problem, so I disabled them one by one until I found the issue.

Comment: ah okay, makes sense. thx

Comment: I disabled the "AdBlock" extension and it fixed it for me (so different blocking extension but it still worked) - will give uBlock a go

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem couple of times, but in my case I think it always happened after messing with debugger and it's settings.

I've fixed it by clicking "Restore defaults and reload" in DevTools settings.

Comment: This actually solved it for me as well.

Comment: just as an FYI to others, I tried this and it didn't work but I have AdBlock installed, so @skeets solution works for me

Answer (score 1):

Got this error at v70. When I turned off all patterns in blackboxing setting this error gone

[image: Screenshot of Framework Blackbox Patterns settings]

Comment: how to go to this settings, i can't see it in chrome settings

Comment: @vikrant devtools -> top right corner -> three dots -> settings

Answer (score 0):

For newer Chrome releases (it's 120 for me), this settings can be found under `DevTools  Preferences  Console  Preserve log upon navigation`.